# Buttons in LinearLayout not filling entire space programmatically

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android

So I have a LinearLayout in horizontal mode which I add buttons to at random times in code and I like them all to fill up the space equally.

This is my current code so far:

```
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.FILL;
```

and I add it to my view here:

```
linearLayout.addView(button, layoutParams);
```

All it does is add the buttons as if it was `wrap_content` and not expanding their width to fill up the available space as in the buttons look left justified.

I also have tried `linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL);` and

```
linearLayout.setWeightSum(++weightSum);
linearLayout.addView(button, layoutParams);
```

where `layoutParams` in this case is:

```
layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
```

I also tried setting the layout width to zero per answers to other questions.

Am I missing another technique?

**Edit:** I figured it out, I forgot to set the width of the LinearLayout to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Button`'s background has "margins" so they will always have gaps even if there's no space between buttons. You have to change background to your own image which doesn't have these margins.

**EDIT**: You should use weights for buttons.

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.weight = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Button" + (i + 1));
        linearLayout.addView(button, params);
    }
```

Comment: Gaps are okay but the problem is the buttons are not expanding to fill up the available space so all the buttons look like they are left justified.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Here's an updated answer.

Comment: I think I already tried this including setting the width to 0. It doesn't work :(

Comment: And what about `weight`? Have you tried it too? I've just tried it on my device and it works. Just create a test project and run this code. You'll see it works.

Comment: I did, see the last parameter in last code block. I also ran it on my device albeit not in a new project. If it helps, it's a LinearLayout in a Dialog.

Comment: Oops I must apologize, all the techniques except the Gravity one works. I made a mistake with the LinearLayout by accidentally setting it's width to `wrap_content`